# Way to display View block only when a specific option is selected in Facet

Tags: views, search

I have a view block which I want to display on page only when a specific item in facet is selected (eg Year) .
I am struggling to get this done , I tried with contextual filter but it seems it doesnt work with Solr index . 
Any pointer on how can i control the behavior of display of my view block on facet combo.

Thanks!
Carol

Answer (score 0):

In common situation, when facet is active - you have GET params in your url. You can use it as condition for programmatically display view. For example

```
if (!empty($_GET['my_facet'])) {
  print views_embed_view('view_name', 'display_name');
}
```